# AndroidStudio - parallel deployment on multiple devices (not one after another)

Tags: deployment, parallel-processing, android-studio, device

Hello people of the internet,

I am creating an application which involves communication between multiple different devices. For testing purposes, I regularly deploy the application to up to four devices at a time.

In AndroidStudio this is possible by selecting multiple devices in the device-chooser dialog and it works quite well. However, The deployment is executed sequential, so the app is deployed one device at a time instead of running the command on all devices at once.

That means that the deployment on device two starts after the deployment on device one is finished which consumes a pretty large amount of time.

Is there any way to make Android studio execute the necessary commands parallel instead of sequential? In Eclipse its quite easy by just pressing "run" multiple times because the deployment is done as a background task independently for each device.

Thanks in advance!